# Mac Catalyst window position

Tags: ios, swift, mac-catalyst

It is possible to set the size of `UIWindow` with `windowScene.sizeRestrictions`. Is it also possible to set the position on the screen of a `UIWindowScene`?

Answer (score -1):

There is no public API to change the position of `UIWindowScene`.

If you don't mind using a private/hidden API though, you can change the position of the window by calling `NSWindow.setFrameOrigin()`. You can use a library like [Dynamic](https://github.com/mhdhejazi/Dynamic) to do the following:

```swift
let nsWindow = Dynamic.NSApplication.sharedApplication.delegate.hostWindowForUIWindow(view.window)
nsWindow.setFrameOrigin(NSMakePoint(50, 100))
```

Or, if you just want to center the window, you can try:

```swift
nsWindow.center()
```